# Why do I get an error when I add break statement in While loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, loops, compiler-errors, break

So this is a segment of the code I ran using vcvarsall, a tool from Microsoft Visual Studio.

```
   Running = true;
    while (Running);
    {
        MSG Message;
        BOOL MessageResult = GetMessageA(&Message, 0, 0, 0);
        if (MessageResult > 0)
        {
            TranslateMessage(&Message);
            DispatchMessage(&Message);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

I get this error from the commmand line:

> error C2043: illegal break

I did some research and found out from the MSDN,

```
 A break is legal only within a do, for, while, or switch statement.
```

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2043?view=vs-2019

So how do I resolve this error? From other C++ documentation and examples I found, this is legal. Is this a problem specific to C++ code run in Visual Studio? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `;` after `while (Running)`.

Comment: Thanks! case solved! Turns out the problem is way less complicated and it compiled successfully now!

Comment: To elaborate on songyuanyao's comment: `while (Running);` is equivalent to `while (Running) { }`. And then, the rest of the code is executed _outside/after_ the (empty) loop.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be a syntax error! Do not add a `;` after a loop! Also, you are allowed to add break statements as long as it is within a loop, switch statement.

Comment: It's not a syntax error. Well, not in the usual sense, that is, it's not an invalid use of C++ syntax. The code is legal and its meaning is well defined. And it's sometimes useful to have a semicolon as the body of a loop. But it's definitely a mistake here! +1.